# .NET 4.0 slower than earlier versions, is that true?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are .NET 4.0 Runtime slower than .NET 2.0 Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864223/are-net-4-0-runtime-slower-than-net-2-0-runtime)

Hello All,

We are planning to move to .NET framework 4.0 sometime soon...
I don't remember the refernce or link, but recently, I read about the latest framework being a little slow in performance when compared to its predecessors.

Is that true? has anybody done any tests or have some valid arguments to support this?

Comment: Maybe you read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864223/are-net-4-0-runtime-slower-than-net-2-0-runtime

Comment: I'm sure I heard this about 1.1.  And 2.0.  And definitely 3.  Let's not mention 3.5, and the hindenberg-like disaster that was 3.5 sp1.

When will you EVER not hear this, is what I'm wondering.

Comment: @0xA3, I think, I can agree with you, probably I didn't search stackoverflow enough before posting this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to make a general statement about the performance of .NET 4.0 compared to earlier versions. Microsoft is constantly improving the framework, thus making performance improvements. Performance is improved both in the BCL as in the runtime itself. For instance, cold startup time is improved dramatically and the performance of the GC has improved both in 3.5sp1 and in 4.0. On the other hand, the framework is getting bigger and this means more code. More code means more page misses, means slower performance.

On the other hand, .NET 4.0 introduces new techniques that that can drastically improve the performance of your code (such as the TPL). And don’t forget that new techniques will be introduced that improve the developer performance, which is the most important part of all.

So don't get influenced by sentiment and gossip. Even if .NET 4.0 is slower, this shouldn't worry you. You should benchmark if that part of the framework is fast enough for your requirements. If it isn't, you can always come back here at SO and ask how that particular scenario can be improved. It is almost always possible to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running .NET 4.0 with VS2010.  The compiled apps seem to run decently, however the development IDE was built using WPF (afaik) and is extremely slow.  So slow that I've become prejudiced against WPF as a viable UI solution for my own projects.  It seems WPF is good for small stuff but doesn't scale up to larger and more complex UI very well.

Comment: I remember hearing on a Hearding Code podcast that VS2010 was a WPF/COM monster, so it could just be that WPF + lots of COM interop is slow.  Hard to say.

Comment: @Cory, I agree with your comments...  VS2010 reminds me of one of the earlier versions of Eclipse, when it was a real hog to load and run (it's much improved since then).  For some reason, just to me personally, it is **so** Eclipse-like...!

Comment: I agree on VS2010IDE performance indeed it is pathetic!!!

Comment: I'm happy with VS2010 IDE performance, it good enough on any mid-range PC with 4GB of RAM. The nice thing about building VS 2010 in WPF is that it forced the Microsoft WPF development team to "eat their own dogfood" (so to speak), in the process ironing out an enormous amount of bugs that never made it to the final WPF release.